# Sieve of eratosphenes algorithm

Tags: erlang, prime-factoring

I'm attempting to implement a sieve of eratosphenes in erlang. However I cannot get past the second step of the algorithm. Im filling in marked entries with p so that when I go through the list until I find a value greater than p I will know that it is also prime.

```
    -module(sieve).
    -export([primes/0]).

    primes() -> L = lists:seq(2,20),
    mark(L,2).

    mark(L,P) -> mark(L,P,2,[]).

    mark([],_,_,N) -> N;
    mark([_|T],P,C,N) when C =:= P -> mark(T,P,C+1,[N|[P]]);
    mark([H|T],P,C,N) -> mark(T,P,C,[N|[H]]).
```

Ive also tried appending with a ++ but that produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The above code runs for only one pass.

```
primes() ->
    List = lists:seq(2,100),
    mark([], List).

mark(Primes, []) ->
    lists:reverse(Primes);
mark(Primes, _List = [H| T]) ->
    mark([H | Primes], H, T, []).

mark(Primes, _P, [], NewList) -> 
    mark(Primes, lists:reverse(NewList));
mark(Primes, P, [H | T], NewList) when H rem P == 0 ->
    mark(Primes, P, T, NewList);
mark(Primes, P,[H | T], NewList) ->
    mark(Primes, P, T, [H | NewList]).
```

Works even without reverse, but to maintain proper order we can do reverse or ++

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is for education, storing prime numbers in a list is OK, and vinod's solution is good. But if you have to use this list, then I think that an ETS table (ordered set) may be more convenient.

Another point, a weakness of erathostene algorithm is that you first creates a huge list (if you need many of them) an then remove most of the elements. You can easily divide by 2 the initial list `L = [2|lists:seq(3,Max,2)]`. You can also initialize the list/table without the multiples of 2,3,5, it is shorter to create, and shorter to eliminate.